# Get Numberformat in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Rng1 As Range
Dim ShName As String
With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng1 = .Range("A2:E" & LastRow)
    ShName = .Name
End With

Charts.Add
With ActiveChart
    .ChartType = xlLine
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "CPU Utilization"
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Duration of Run(hh:mm)" 'X axis name
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "CPU Utilization (%)" 'y-axis name
    .Legend.Position = xlLegendPositionBottom
    .SetSourceData Source:=Rng1
    .Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=ShName

End With
```

I want to add numberformat in above code i tried below code but did'nt work(Method or Data not Found Error)

```
.NumberFormat = "[$-F400]h:mm:ss AM/PM"
.NumberFormat = "h:mm;@"
```

also want to set width and height of the graph and add display units thousand in format axis. pls. provide solution for same.

Answer (score 0):

For the **Number format**, you must assign the number format to some *child* of the chart. For example : `Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.NumberFormat`
For **Gap width** see [MSDN-ChartGroup.GapWidth Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195812%28v=office.15%29.aspx).
I don't understand how you want to display thousands in time format, but the custom format for thousand separated values looks like this `"# ##0,00"`

If you want to experiment with charts, I recommend using macro recorder. That's how I got to this.